# How to check in code which is checked out from different repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

We deal with two repositories one at client side and one at our end.
I checked out some code from client repository and made some changes.Now I want to check in the same code in our repository. How it can be done ?
Also is there any good way to sync two repositories ?
**PS:** I am using Tortoise SVN.

~Ajinkya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I got some workaround.
I exported the code from client repository made some changes then I exported it(Right click on folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Export) to new location.Then imported the code to our repository.It helped me for now.
Please share if anybody else have any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a few options.

1. if you can use relocate option, you should be able to commit changes another repository.
2. If two repositories are simply dulpicated, you can try create a patch.

Above two may not be valid option. Read more:
3. Use merging tools to merge two checkout. Simple and easy.
4. Try Git, it can work with svn.

Comment: Thanks , these are more than enough. Can you please elaborate these as I am not much familiar with relocating, patching and Git ?

Comment: @Ajinkya
* relocating requires they have same repository, which I assume you may not, :).
* patch is like to create a list of diff files from old codebase and apply to new codebase. 
two option above may not help much if you are on totally different repository. 
* Git is mean to provide better management on branches, even different repositories. I highly recommend you to have a look at GIT, it may help you for your later development.

* The merging tools is most suitable choice in my opinion.

Comment: I am using completely diff repo so first two option may not be so helpful. I am using winmerge but merging seems to be tedious when you have tons of changes. So only option available is Git. Will give a try to Git.

Answer (score 0):

as far as my knowledge is concerned we cannot commit the code to a repository unless it is checked out from the same repository.

one way to commit in your case is upload the downloaded code from client repository to your repository,check out the same and make changes and then commit. i know this is not as desired by you.

if you find a better approach plz update so that it helps others too..

TNQ

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to specify where you're checking in.  `svn commit` simply has no option for that.

Comment: Its making my life really difficult.